# What is the growth relationship of the number of digits a number has as numbers increase?

Tags: recreational-mathematics, relations, decimal-expansion

To clarify the question, since I'm sure the wording is awkward:

In the decimal number system, to get from 1 digit to 2, it takes n=10 numbers. To get from 2 to 3, it takes 90 more numbers added to n. . . so on and so forth an you have a relationship like

## digits       n

1             9
2             99
3             999

or something like that. It seems that as n gets very large, digits increment much slower. Is there a way to describe this relationship? Is there some kind of upper bound? I'm puzzled by this because I'm bad at math.

Comment: # number of digits in =~ $\log_{10} n

Answer (score 2):

Let $d(n)$ be the number of digits of a positive integer $n$. Then $$d(n)= 1+ \lfloor \log_{10}(n) \rfloor$$

This uses the floor function and the base 10 logarithm.

The slow growth rate you mentioned is because of the fact that [logarithms, which are the inverse of exponents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm), grow very slowly. You should read that article on logarithms - they are extremely useful in many areas of mathematics.